# How to access byte count of arbitrary number using num_traits?

Tags: rust

I want to implement an extension trait to `std::io::Read` in order to read arbitrary numbers. However I cannot find out, how to get the byte count of an arbitary number using the `num_traits` crate (or what other crate might provide this information):

```rust
use num_traits::FromBytes;
use std::io::{Read, Result};

pub trait ReadNums: Read {
    fn read_num_be<N>(&mut self) -> Result<N>
    where
        N: FromBytes,
    {
        let mut buffer = [0; N::WHAT_HERE];
        self.read_exact(&mut buffer)?;
        Ok(N::from_be_bytes(&buffer))
    }
}

impl<T> ReadNums for T where T: Read {}
```

```ini
[package]
name = "numtrait_test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
num-traits = "0.2.17"
```

I don't know what to put at `N::WHAT_HERE`. I need the respective size of `N` in bytes here as a `const`.
Using nightly features is out of the question for my use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FromBytes` provides the `Bytes` associated type, but since `FromBytes` is also meant to work with arbitrary-precision types like `BigInt`, the `Bytes` type is not necessarily fixed width.

You can, however, force the association to be an array, with a const generic for the size:

```rust
use num_traits::FromBytes;
use std::io::{Read, Result};

pub trait ReadNums: Read {
    fn read_num_be<V, const N: usize>(&mut self) -> Result<V>
    where
        V: FromBytes<Bytes=[u8; N]>,
    {
        let mut buffer = [0; N];
        self.read_exact(&mut buffer)?;
        Ok(V::from_be_bytes(&buffer))
    }
}

impl<T> ReadNums for T where T: Read {}
```

This will work with all of the primitive integer types, since their `FromBytes` implementation take in fixed-sized arrays.

Comment: FYI: https://docs.rs/rw-exact-ext/latest/rw_exact_ext/index.html